# How do I subscript a boolean function in a data frame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have dataframe that looks like this:

```
    key             Candidate   Position duplicates
0   0-39-1  SHRI. BISHNU PADA RAY    1    False
1   0-39-1  SHRI. KULDEEP RAI SHARMA 2    False
2   0-39-1  SHRI TAPAN KUMAR BEPARI  3    False
3   0-39-1  SHRI. P. R. GANESHAN     4    False
4   0-39-1  SMTI. R. S. UMA BHARATTH 5    True
```

I want to have a value 1 if the duplicate value is True and 0 if it is False. There are only these 2 values that this column has. I read a lot of answers for this and have already tried out the following:

`df["duplicates"] = int(df["duplicates"]==True)`
`df["flag_numeric"][df["duplicates"]==True] = 1`

And several other trivial solutions but each time I get the following error:
`'bool' object is not subscriptable`

Since I am new to python, can someone please help me find the right answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting boolean to 0 and 1 can be accomplished by casting to int. Use `astype` method for this:

```
df['duplicates'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
df["duplicates"] = df.duplicates.map(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

> `[df["duplicates"]==True] = 1`

Double equal-sign `==` outside the bracket is also required, make it like: `df[df['column_name'] == value] == 1`

So in your case it would be:

```py
if df[df['duplicates'] == True]: #the double square brackets are important
    return 1
else
    return 0
```

Hope this helps!